# Call a function after all images have completed loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax('html url')
    .done(function(response) {
            var resultHtml = $(response).find("#content").children();
                $("#content").html(resultHtml);                    
                $(document).height();            
    })
```

Here i need to calculate the document height of response . But this response contains multiple images which takes time to load . So document height is less than what is required .

I tried using jquery load function for image -- like this

```
$('img').load(function(){
   $(document).height();
});
```

But in this case too it is not working . However using javascript complete method for images ,it returns correct height (for single image ).

```
 document.getElementById("#image1").complete{
   $(document).height();
 }
```

However my response contains multiple images so getElementById wont work . I want to achieve this using jquery .

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var images= document.images,
length = images.length,
cnt = 0;

[].forEach.call( imgs, function( images) {
    images.addEventListener( 'load', incrementCounter, false );
} );

function incrementCounter() {
    cnt++;
    if ( cnt=== length ) {
        console.log( 'All image load' );
        $(document).height(); //your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this on js:

```
$("img").imagesLoaded(function(){
//do something here, it will run after image loaded, but please attention about browser cache
});
```

It used imagesLoaded.js check out on https://imagesloaded.desandro.com